# Prompts Error upon retrieval of key-value from kv-v2 secrets in Quarkus (Gradle)

Tags: security, backend, quarkus, hashicorp-vault, hashicorp

`application.properties` for the gradle project I am using:

```
%dev.quarkus.vault.url=http://127.0.0.1:8200
%dev.quarkus.vault.authentication.client-token=hvs.6AR6TPhCBYMUkZX0EfqBMDEL
%dev.quarkus.vault.secret-config-kv-path=apps/firstapp/config
```

It gets the key-value pairs successfully when invoked via cmd locally.

```
======= Metadata =======
Key                Value
---                -----
created_time       2023-09-14T06:51:21.8766136Z
custom_metadata    <nil>
deletion_time      n/a
destroyed          false
version            1

======= Data =======
Key            Value
---            -----
productCode    abc
```

On project compilation, the following error prompts:

```
2023-09-15 00:41:08,243 ERROR [io.qua.run.Application] (Quarkus Main Thread) Failed to start application (with profile [dev]): java.lang.RuntimeException: Failed to start quarkus
        at io.quarkus.runner.ApplicationImpl.doStart(Unknown Source)
        at io.quarkus.runtime.Application.start(Application.java:101)
        at io.quarkus.runtime.ApplicationLifecycleManager.run(ApplicationLifecycleManager.java:111)
        at io.quarkus.runtime.Quarkus.run(Quarkus.java:71)
        at io.quarkus.runtime.Quarkus.run(Quarkus.java:44)
        at io.quarkus.runtime.Quarkus.run(Quarkus.java:124)
        at io.quarkus.runner.GeneratedMain.main(Unknown Source)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DirectMethodHandleAccessor.invoke(DirectMethodHandleAccessor.java:104)
        at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:578)
        at io.quarkus.runner.bootstrap.StartupActionImpl$1.run(StartupActionImpl.java:104)
        at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:1623)
Caused by: java.util.concurrent.RejectedExecutionException
        at org.jboss.threads.RejectingExecutor.execute(RejectingExecutor.java:38)
        at org.jboss.threads.EnhancedQueueExecutor.rejectShutdown(EnhancedQueueExecutor.java:2136)
        at org.jboss.threads.EnhancedQueueExecutor$SchedulerTask.schedule(EnhancedQueueExecutor.java:3093)
        at org.jboss.threads.EnhancedQueueExecutor.schedule(EnhancedQueueExecutor.java:936)
        at io.smallrye.mutiny.operators.uni.UniFailOnTimeout$UniFailOnTimeoutProcessor.onSubscribe(UniFailOnTimeout.java:50)
        at io.smallrye.mutiny.vertx.AsyncResultUni.subscribe(AsyncResultUni.java:27)
        at io.smallrye.mutiny.operators.AbstractUni.subscribe(AbstractUni.java:36)
        at io.smallrye.mutiny.operators.uni.UniFailOnTimeout.subscribe(UniFailOnTimeout.java:36)
        at io.smallrye.mutiny.operators.AbstractUni.subscribe(AbstractUni.java:36)
        at io.smallrye.mutiny.operators.uni.UniOnItemTransform.subscribe(UniOnItemTransform.java:22)
        at io.smallrye.mutiny.operators.AbstractUni.subscribe(AbstractUni.java:36)
        at io.smallrye.mutiny.operators.uni.UniOnFailureTransform.subscribe(UniOnFailureTransform.java:31)
        at io.smallrye.mutiny.operators.AbstractUni.subscribe(AbstractUni.java:36)
        at io.smallrye.mutiny.operators.uni.UniOnFailureTransform.subscribe(UniOnFailureTransform.java:31)
        at io.smallrye.mutiny.operators.AbstractUni.subscribe(AbstractUni.java:36)
        at io.smallrye.mutiny.operators.uni.UniOnFailureTransform.subscribe(UniOnFailureTransform.java:31)
        at io.smallrye.mutiny.operators.AbstractUni.subscribe(AbstractUni.java:36)
        at io.smallrye.mutiny.operators.uni.UniOnFailureTransform.subscribe(UniOnFailureTransform.java:31)
        at io.smallrye.mutiny.operators.AbstractUni.subscribe(AbstractUni.java:36)
        at io.smallrye.mutiny.operators.uni.UniOnItemTransform.subscribe(UniOnItemTransform.java:22)
        at io.smallrye.mutiny.operators.AbstractUni.subscribe(AbstractUni.java:36)
        at io.smallrye.mutiny.operators.uni.UniOnItemTransformToUni$UniOnItemTransformToUniProcessor.performInnerSubscription(UniOnItemTransformToUni.java:81)
        at io.smallrye.mutiny.operators.uni.UniOnItemTransformToUni$UniOnItemTransformToUniProcessor.onItem(UniOnItemTransformToUni.java:57)
        at io.smallrye.mutiny.operators.uni.builders.UniCreateFromKnownItem$KnownItemSubscription.forward(UniCreateFromKnownItem.java:38)
        at io.smallrye.mutiny.operators.uni.builders.UniCreateFromKnownItem.subscribe(UniCreateFromKnownItem.java:23)
        at io.smallrye.mutiny.operators.AbstractUni.subscribe(AbstractUni.java:36)
        at io.smallrye.mutiny.operators.uni.UniOnItemTransformToUni.subscribe(UniOnItemTransformToUni.java:25)
        at io.smallrye.mutiny.operators.AbstractUni.subscribe(AbstractUni.java:36)
        at io.smallrye.mutiny.operators.uni.UniOnItemTransform.subscribe(UniOnItemTransform.java:22)
        at io.smallrye.mutiny.operators.AbstractUni.subscribe(AbstractUni.java:36)
        at io.smallrye.mutiny.operators.uni.UniBlockingAwait.await(UniBlockingAwait.java:60)
        at io.smallrye.mutiny.groups.UniAwait.atMost(UniAwait.java:65)
        at io.smallrye.mutiny.groups.UniAwait.indefinitely(UniAwait.java:46)
        at io.quarkus.vault.runtime.config.VaultConfigSource.fetchSecrets(VaultConfigSource.java:132)
        at io.quarkus.vault.runtime.config.VaultConfigSource.lambda$fetchSecrets$2(VaultConfigSource.java:128)
        at java.base/java.util.ArrayList.forEach(ArrayList.java:1511)
        at io.quarkus.vault.runtime.config.VaultConfigSource.fetchSecrets(VaultConfigSource.java:128)
        at io.quarkus.vault.runtime.config.VaultConfigSource.lambda$fetchSecrets$0(VaultConfigSource.java:121)
        at java.base/java.util.Optional.ifPresent(Optional.java:178)
        at io.quarkus.vault.runtime.config.VaultConfigSource.fetchSecrets(VaultConfigSource.java:121)
        at io.quarkus.vault.runtime.config.VaultConfigSource.fetchSecretsFirstTime(VaultConfigSource.java:104)
        at io.quarkus.vault.runtime.config.VaultConfigSource.getSecretConfig(VaultConfigSource.java:82)
        at io.quarkus.vault.runtime.config.VaultConfigSource.getValue(VaultConfigSource.java:63)
        at io.smallrye.config.ConfigValueConfigSourceWrapper.getConfigValue(ConfigValueConfigSourceWrapper.java:20)
        at io.smallrye.config.SmallRyeConfigSources.getValue(SmallRyeConfigSources.java:29)
        at io.smallrye.config.SmallRyeConfigSourceInterceptorContext.proceed(SmallRyeConfigSourceInterceptorContext.java:20)
        at io.smallrye.config.SecretKeysConfigSourceInterceptor.getValue(SecretKeysConfigSourceInterceptor.java:24)
        at io.smallrye.config.SmallRyeConfigSourceInterceptorContext.proceed(SmallRyeConfigSourceInterceptorContext.java:20)
        at io.smallrye.config.RelocateConfigSourceInterceptor.getValue(RelocateConfigSourceInterceptor.java:25)
        at io.smallrye.config.SmallRyeConfigSourceInterceptorContext.proceed(SmallRyeConfigSourceInterceptorContext.java:20)
        at io.smallrye.config.RelocateConfigSourceInterceptor.getValue(RelocateConfigSourceInterceptor.java:25)
        at io.smallrye.config.SmallRyeConfigSourceInterceptorContext.proceed(SmallRyeConfigSourceInterceptorContext.java:20)
        at io.smallrye.config.RelocateConfigSourceInterceptor.getValue(RelocateConfigSourceInterceptor.java:25)
        at io.smallrye.config.SmallRyeConfigSourceInterceptorContext.proceed(SmallRyeConfigSourceInterceptorContext.java:20)
        at io.smallrye.config.ProfileConfigSourceInterceptor.getProfileValue(ProfileConfigSourceInterceptor.java:56)
        at io.smallrye.config.ProfileConfigSourceInterceptor.getValue(ProfileConfigSourceInterceptor.java:37)
        at io.smallrye.config.SmallRyeConfigSourceInterceptorContext.proceed(SmallRyeConfigSourceInterceptorContext.java:20)
        at io.smallrye.config.ExpressionConfigSourceInterceptor.getValue(ExpressionConfigSourceInterceptor.java:43)
        at io.smallrye.config.ExpressionConfigSourceInterceptor.getValue(ExpressionConfigSourceInterceptor.java:35)
        at io.smallrye.config.SmallRyeConfigSourceInterceptorContext.proceed(SmallRyeConfigSourceInterceptorContext.java:20)
        at io.smallrye.config.SecretKeysHandlerConfigSourceInterceptor.getValue(SecretKeysHandlerConfigSourceInterceptor.java:25)      
        at io.smallrye.config.SmallRyeConfigSourceInterceptorContext.proceed(SmallRyeConfigSourceInterceptorContext.java:20)
        at io.smallrye.config.FallbackConfigSourceInterceptor.getValue(FallbackConfigSourceInterceptor.java:24)
        at io.smallrye.config.SmallRyeConfigSourceInterceptorContext.proceed(SmallRyeConfigSourceInterceptorContext.java:20)
        at io.smallrye.config.PropertyNamesConfigSourceInterceptor.getValue(PropertyNamesConfigSourceInterceptor.java:17)
        at io.smallrye.config.SmallRyeConfigSourceInterceptorContext.proceed(SmallRyeConfigSourceInterceptorContext.java:20)
        at io.smallrye.config.SmallRyeConfig.getConfigValue(SmallRyeConfig.java:323)
        at io.smallrye.config.SmallRyeConfig.getValue(SmallRyeConfig.java:230)
        at io.smallrye.config.SmallRyeConfig.getOptionalValue(SmallRyeConfig.java:359)
        at io.smallrye.config.SmallRyeConfig.getOptionalValues(SmallRyeConfig.java:373)
        at io.quarkus.vault.runtime.config.DevServicesConfig-1803211619Impl.<init>(Unknown Source)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DirectConstructorHandleAccessor.newInstance(DirectConstructorHandleAccessor.java:67)
        at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstanceWithCaller(Constructor.java:500)
        at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:484)
        at io.smallrye.config.ConfigMappingLoader.configMappingObject(ConfigMappingLoader.java:65)
        at io.smallrye.config.ConfigMappingContext.constructGroup(ConfigMappingContext.java:81)
        at io.quarkus.vault.runtime.config.VaultBuildTimeConfig1464628227Impl.<init>(Unknown Source)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DirectConstructorHandleAccessor.newInstance(DirectConstructorHandleAccessor.java:67)
        at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstanceWithCaller(Constructor.java:500)
        at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:484)
        at io.smallrye.config.ConfigMappingLoader.configMappingObject(ConfigMappingLoader.java:65)
        at io.smallrye.config.ConfigMappingContext.constructGroup(ConfigMappingContext.java:81)
        at io.smallrye.config.ConfigMappingContext.constructRoot(ConfigMappingContext.java:77)
        at io.smallrye.config.ConfigMappingProvider.mapConfigurationInternal(ConfigMappingProvider.java:977)
        at io.smallrye.config.ConfigMappingProvider.lambda$mapConfiguration$3(ConfigMappingProvider.java:959)
        at io.smallrye.config.SecretKeys.doUnlocked(SecretKeys.java:28)
        at io.smallrye.config.ConfigMappingProvider.mapConfiguration(ConfigMappingProvider.java:959)
        at io.smallrye.config.ConfigMappings.mapConfiguration(ConfigMappings.java:91)
        at io.smallrye.config.SmallRyeConfigBuilder.build(SmallRyeConfigBuilder.java:630)
        at io.quarkus.runtime.generated.Config.readConfig(Unknown Source)
        at io.quarkus.deployment.steps.RuntimeConfigSetup.deploy(Unknown Source)
        ... 11 more
        Suppressed: java.util.concurrent.RejectedExecutionException: Executor is being shut down
                at org.jboss.threads.EnhancedQueueExecutor.rejectShutdown(EnhancedQueueExecutor.java:2138)
                ... 100 more
```

Expected Behavior:

The project compiles successfully and the secrets could be accessed using the following code:

```
    @ConfigProperty(name = "productCode")
    String productCode;
```

Did I miss something? How should it be fixed?

Comment: Hi ashnove, Welcome to StackOverflow. I'm not sure your [question meets the criteria](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic)... In the meantime, help us help you by showing us the command line that works (not just the output). You can also [turn on auditing](https://developer.hashicorp.com/vault/docs/audit#enabling-disabling-audit-devices) and see if the server even requests the secret at all. Connectivity issues are frequent.